# Extracting the Data basis on system or machine date and time

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have an exchange rate data. Given below is the data:

```
structure(list(Currency = c("INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", 
"INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", 
"INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", 
"INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "INR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", 
"IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", 
"IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", 
"IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "IDR", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", 
"PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", 
"PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", 
"PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "PLN", "USD", "USD", 
"USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
"USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
"USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", 
"SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", 
"SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", 
"SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", "SEK", 
"SEK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", 
"CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", 
"CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", "CZK", 
"CZK", "CZK", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", 
"SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", 
"SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", 
"SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", 
"CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", 
"CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", 
"CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", 
"RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", 
"RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", 
"RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "RUB", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "INR", "IDR", "PLN", 
"USD", "GBP", "SEK", "CZK", "SGD", "CNY", "RUB", "EUR", "MXN", 
"MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", 
"MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", 
"MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", "MXN", 
"MXN", "INR", "IDR", "PLN", "USD", "GBP", "SEK", "CZK", "SGD", 
"CNY", "RUB", "EUR", "MXN"), Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), Exchnage_Rate = c(0.01264, 
0.01259, 0.01247, 0.01238, 0.0127, 0.01249, 0.01244, 0.01209, 
0.01187, 0.01196, 0.01257, 0.0125, 0.01223, 0.01223, 0.01288, 
0.01281, 0.01287, 0.01276, 0.01301, 0.01267, 0.01296, 0.01264, 
0.01265, 0.0125, 0.01266, 0.01256, 0.01204, 0.01224, 6e-05, 5.98e-05, 
5.9e-05, 5.94e-05, 6.13e-05, 5.98e-05, 5.93e-05, 5.81e-05, 5.77e-05, 
5.79e-05, 6.11e-05, 6e-05, 6.2e-05, 6.27e-05, 6.26e-05, 6.3e-05, 
6.24e-05, 6.22e-05, 6.39e-05, 6.4e-05, 6.45e-05, 6.39e-05, 6.43e-05, 
6.41e-05, 6.6e-05, 6.4e-05, 5.5e-05, 6.16e-05, 0.2405, 0.23961, 
0.23713, 0.23759, 0.2322, 0.22847, 0.23417, 0.23252, 0.23337, 
0.23082, 0.23323, 0.23248, 0.23336, 0.23179, 0.23224, 0.23295, 
0.23314, 0.23553, 0.23263, 0.228, 0.22817, 0.23484, 0.23174, 
0.23506, 0.23288, 0.23283, 0.2197, 0.22014, 0.80583, 0.81769, 
0.81143, 0.82493, 0.85724, 0.85472, 0.85416, 0.85732, 0.86133, 
0.88136, 0.87778, 0.87415, 0.87067, 0.87875, 0.89132, 0.89403, 
0.8984, 0.87951, 0.89619, 0.90835, 0.91389, 0.89668, 0.90775, 
0.89267, 0.90671, 0.90721, 0.91044, 0.91894, 1.1407, 1.13706, 
1.13719, 1.13597, 1.14877, 1.1289, 1.12194, 1.11542, 1.12225, 
1.12001, 1.12216, 1.10936, 1.142, 1.17025, 1.16245, 1.15614, 
1.13275, 1.11691, 1.80994, 1.10416, 1.12331, 1.1568, 1.17364, 
1.17051, 1.18646, 1.16307, 1.12671, 1.14633, 0.10216, 0.0994, 
0.09723, 0.09513, 0.09726, 0.0956, 0.09757, 0.094, 0.09674, 0.09607, 
0.09679, 0.0973, 0.09635, 0.09483, 0.09584, 0.09401, 0.09422, 
0.0947, 0.0937, 0.09254, 0.09338, 0.09294, 0.09477, 0.0955, 0.09401, 
0.09444, 0.09037, 0.09348, 0.0395, 0.03934, 0.03947, 0.03927, 
0.03866, 0.03846, 0.03907, 0.0388, 0.03884, 0.03862, 0.03852, 
0.03883, 0.03879, 0.03899, 0.03873, 0.03896, 0.03871, 0.03934, 
0.03896, 0.03848, 0.03868, 0.03917, 0.03916, 0.03935, 0.0396, 
0.0331, 0.0366, 0.03691, 0.61428, 0.61744, 0.61903, 0.62315, 
0.64019, 0.62713, 0.62754, 0.62695, 0.63022, 0.63622, 0.64075, 
0.63979, 0.64647, 0.65187, 0.65308, 0.6568, 0.65097, 0.65012, 
0.654, 0.65412, 0.66153, 0.6587, 0.66367, 0.66208, 0.66551, 0.65106, 
0.63837, 0.65294, 0.12746, 0.12943, 0.12916, 0.13021, 0.13351, 
0.12913, 0.12534, 0.12523, 0.12541, 0.12653, 0.12642, 0.1271, 
0.12966, 0.13145, 0.13268, 0.13276, 0.13014, 0.1281, 0.13071, 
0.12695, 0.12828, 0.12736, 0.12907, 0.12776, 0.13068, 0.12975, 
0.12894, 0.13019, 0.0143, 0.01454, 0.01421, 0.01319, 0.0138, 
0.01363, 0.01373, 0.01256, 0.01312, 0.01345, 0.01327, 0.01255, 
0.0133, 0.01336, 0.01334, 0.01387, 0.01377, 0.0139, 0.01411, 
0.01362, 0.01414, 0.01406, 0.01409, 0.01439, 0.01434, 0.01357, 
0.0114, 0.01259, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.01192, 6.1e-05, 0.22483, 
0.90058, 1.11213, 0.09536, 0.03714, 0.63709, 0.12622, 0.01283, 
1, 0.04293, 0.04339, 0.04461, 0.04423, 0.04369, 0.04294, 0.04609, 
0.04487, 0.04585, 0.0439, 0.04337, 0.04449, 0.04556, 0.04584, 
0.04586, 0.04702, 0.04607, 0.04574, 0.04699, 0.04529, 0.0464, 
0.04696, 0.04644, 0.04714, 0.04824, 0.04625, 0.03803, 0.03885, 
0.04053, 0.01192, 6.1e-05, 0.22483, 0.90058, 1.11213, 0.09536, 
0.03714, 0.63709, 0.12622, 0.01283, 1, 0.04053)), row.names = c(NA, 
-360L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Currently i want to extract only the data such that it should be based on my system date. For example today is 16-June-2020, so i need to extract only those data which is of 2020 and month should be previous month i.e May

currently i am running this code

```
exchangeRate<-exchangeRate%>%filter(Month==5 & Year=="2020")
```

However i want it to be automated basis on my system date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sys.Date` to get today's date and use `format` to extract month and year, i.e.

```
i1 <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y'))
i2 <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), '%m'))

#Use them to filter
df %>% 
 filter(Month == i2 - 1 & Year == i1)
```